# Prevent a folder access by direct url and give access to loggedin users (codeigniter)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want my document folder to be shown to the loggedin users only and i want to prevernt direct access to folder by url. unauthorized users cant accsss the folder by direct url

mydomain.com/folder/file.pdf

can be viewed by loggedin users and if anyone type it in browser it should not open up until session is created.